# What is the best way to connect to and query a MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

This is a pretty easy question but I would like some clarity on something.

I have seen a number of different ways to connect and query a MySQL Database using PHP but which is the best way to connect and create a query using PHP?

Comment: the only one i can think to is: it depends :)

Answer (score 9):

By far the best way is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). You can do this using PDO or mysqli, but I prefer the PDO extension for its named parameters.

Why are prepared statements by far the best way? Because they take care of parameter quoting and escaping for you.

#### Bad, old, error-prone, tedious way:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
                       password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'");
```

You can bet that, if you've written an application like this, you will have forgotten at some point to escape the user input, and left a gaping SQL injection hole.

#### Nice prepared statement way:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE password=:password");
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt->execute();
```

Escaping is done for you, and you don't even have to worry about putting quotes around the parameter types that need them.

Comment: Yay PDO! You can even skip the call to `bindParam` and pass the params directly to `execute`:  `$stmt->execute(array(':password' => $password));`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [object-oriented versions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), assuming your php version is new enough to support 'em. They're far cleaner IMHO than the random function soup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's quite as simple as saying *"the best way is..."*

Personally, I hardly ever connect to a database using my own code, I normally have a framework doing that for me.  That said, I'd use the PHP Data Object (PDO) approach to connect and query a database, if I were writing a small standalone application.

See [the manual pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for all the information and examples you'll need.